Specify a field in query only when it is not-null in Micronaut Data
Following is part of my Kotlin code written using Micronaut framework:
import io.micronaut.data.annotation.MappedEntity
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue
import jakarta.persistence.Table

@MappedEntity
@Table(name = "special", schema = "abc")
data class SpecialEntity(
    val uuid: Uuid,

    @GeneratedValue
    val createdAt: Instant? = null
)

import io.micronaut.data.jdbc.annotation.JdbcRepository
import io.micronaut.data.repository.kotlin.CoroutineCrudRepository
import java.util.UUID

@JdbcRepository
interface SpecialEntityRepository : CoroutineCrudRepository<SpecialEntity, UUID> {
    suspend fun saveAll(entities: Iterable<SpecialEntity>): ArrayList<SpecialEntity>
}

The problem I am facing is that because of the GeneratedValue annotation, Micronaut omits this field from the query that is used to insert an entity to database. This was what I wanted initially. But now there is a use-case to set the value manually sometimes.
I have checked out other annotations like @DateCreated which does not work because it always sets the current timestamp. @Query annotation also does not work because the query needs to be static but I need to do batch insert.
Basically what I want is some way to include the field in the insert query when it is non-null. When it is null, it should be omitted from the query. What would be the best way to do that?

@ColumnTransformer(write = "COALESCE(?, now())") worked!
